# The program constantly listening to HTTP Server Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am a beginner programmer in Swift (Xcode 7.3.1 iOS 9).

My question is: How to write a program that continuously listen to the HTTP server if the server sends parameter can get.

It does not require notification to get
Only when the server parameter sent
Program parameters get.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CocoaAsyncSocket` or similar.
[Here](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) you can find info about how to use it